# Are there any free but comparable alternatives to Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, digital, photo-editing

Does anyone have any recommendations for free software that provides the key features of Lightroom in one package? The main things I am looking for are:

- RAW photo editing
- Library management
- Multiple catalogs
- Rich keyword/tag support

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a more affordable program than Lightroom?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4690/is-there-a-more-affordable-program-than-lightroom)

Comment: Free as in no-cost, or free as in open source?

Comment: free as in no cost, open-source is welcome too :)

Comment: In that case, in addition to the question Imre linked, take a look at [What tools are available for RAW image processing in Linux?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/471/what-tools-are-available-for-raw-image-processing-in-linux); some of the suggestions are cross-platform.

Comment: @mattdm I cannot think of one software that cost money and is open source. I cannot think of any software that cost nothing and is closed source.

Comment: @Gapton: The second is easy; Picasa, for example, is zero cost but closed source. I don't think there is any for-money open source software in _this_ particular domain, but it's common in general. (For example, Red Hat Enterprise Linux.)

Comment: Have you tried **Picnik** (http://www.picnik.com)? It is free, easy to use and has a lot of functionality as well.

Answer (score 10):

[RawTherapee](http://www.rawtherapee.com/) is a decent open source alternative to Lightroom.

Comment: Until it crashes that is. The program is very unstable, both on Windows and on Linux.

Comment: I've never had a problem with it crashing. Stability problems can be caused by a wide range of underlying system issues. In any case, it's free, so it's worth checking out.

Comment: That's strange. I've never had it crash on me but to be very fair it's not a program I use since I don't really understand the flow of RawTherapee. I use Lightroom mostly.

Answer (score 8):

You could try [Darktable](http://www.darktable.org). It's available for Linux (and OS X) and resembles Lightroom.

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches here:

1. To use all-in-one applications like Lightroom or Aperture that
   provide editing and cataloging capabilities within the same
   interface
2. Use different applications for different purposes - RAW editor/Photoshop to editing and an image management software for cataloging.

I suggest you to try both ways before coming into a final decision.

We, at Daminion Software, adhere the second approach - and I suggest you to check out our [Daminion](http://daminion.net).

It's free, supports multi-user environment, can automatically sync your tags with the Camera RAW metadata (NEF, CR2, MWG, etc...), support for hierarchical keywords and categories.

I suggest you take a look at [Raw Therapee](http://rawtherapee.com) as a decent free RAW editor.

BTW why you did not mention your platform (PC, Mac, Linux) and your preferable Camera RAW format. It's not free but many Nikon photographers use CaptureNX to edit RAW files.

Comment: Please make a more obvious statement that you are associated with "Daminion Software" just to let people know that you are affiliated

Answer (score 4):

i think that picasa (from google) can do this, but it's not as powerful.

It is free as in beer, though.

Comment: Picasa is a jpeg editor, not a raw editor.

Comment: http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en-US&answer=15625&topic=1689793 :) it is more limited than lightroom, but it edits raw files.

Comment: Thanks...I should have checked about the latest version before commenting. (+1)

Comment: @whuber You're right about Picasa being a JPEG editor: it converts RAW files automatically, and gives no control over the RAW conversion process.  What you edit in the program is then the converted JPEG.  This causes problems [like this one.](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/picasa/Nu8BBaZLQfs/78TGA16SaCQJ)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [XnView](http://www.xnview.com). It does what you want and, also, it has the advantage that it does need to Import the files in a catalog.

Same stands for [FastStone Viewer](http://www.faststone.org) which has a very nice interface, however its catalog engine isn't so featured.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Light Zone is free and much like Lightroom. Give it a try. It's free

http://lightzoneproject.org/