# Why does my computer show an image shot in RAW + JPEG as two JPEGs instead of one RAW and one JPEG?

Tags: raw, workflow, canon-600d

I shot images in RAW + JPEG mode in Canon T3i. There are double images, but both of them are JPEGs. When I view in camera, I see the files size as 26 MB, but when I open the camera folder in computer I get both of them as JPEGs (for example, img001.jpg and img001.jpg). Am I missing something  ?

Attached is the screenshot of my explorer. How is it even possible to store the two images with the same file name in the same folder ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What you are seeing is a poor example of user interface design.** There are two files with two different names for each RAW+JPEG set. You can easily prove this by using a Command Prompt (CMD.EXE) and listing the directory (DIR command).

**Something in your system is screwing with your mind** by hiding the RAW extension (CR2 IIRC) and showing it as another JPEG. If you installed something to interpret your RAW files, I would uninstall it and get Adobe Camera RAW or Lightroom (if you want to manage your images too).

Comment: hmm.. Let me  check. I guess both Adobe Camera RAW and Lightroom are licensed.

Comment: @VinothKumar In [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/are-there-any-free-but-comparable-alternatives-to-lightroom) alternatives for Lightroom are presented.

Comment: @VinothKumar - Which software did you install? If it is the one that camera with your camera, try the microsoft codecs. If it is the microsoft codecs, try the one that came with your camera! In any case, the one you are using is doing  you a disservice.

Comment: @Itai : I haven't yet installed any software to process RAW files. I'm on a vacation and computer at my guest's places is very, very old (with 512 MB RAM). So I'll have to go home to check :(

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. After using the camera for a while I found when I switched to Jpeg+Raw I copied the files over to the folder on my PC and had two jpegs.

This puzzled me as I knew I had used that once before and my PC had no problem with raw files, and I had .CR2 files on my hard drive to prove it. I was convinced the Camera was not now recording the raw files properly.

However the issue was resolved when I used the EOS utility software to transfer the images to my PC.

This time they appeared as they should, each a pair of images, one raw and one jpeg.

Seems it was the drag and drop from the camera as a folder in Windows explorer that was the problem.

Hope that helps someone.