# My pirated copy of Photoshop isn't rendering RAW files correctly. What should I do?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, raw, adobe-camera-raw

i am using photoshop 2017. i thought of updating the camera raw using this link https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-in-installer.html i installed Camera Raw 11.2.

and after installation i am getting this problem for raw files (it shows like this).
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't support pirates.

Comment: @phI downloaded the camera raw by adobe I am not using the cracked version i am using the student version of the photoshop which is similar to the cracked version so that's why I wrote cracked.

Comment: I find it much more likely that [you *are* using a cracked version](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/105283/revisions) and you've now realised that posting that was a bad idea.

Comment: yes it didn't work

Comment: You said you downloaded CR 11.2 - your pic clearly shows 11.1 You'd think raising the issue with Adobe would have spotted that already.

Comment: Also, "the student version ... is similar to the cracked version" is just plain _counterfactual_. The only difference between the student version and the full version is price and licensing terms.

Comment: @PhilipKendall this question has potential for answers - like mattdm's - that are not supportive of illicit software copying at all. (I do not support the term pirate here unless somebody robbed a ship carrying software CDs or cameras :) ). Actually, total neutrality about morality of the asker's intentions (as long as they are not violent, obviously....) would be true Q&A purity :)

Comment: @rackandboneman We already have (e.g.) [Any good alternatives to Lightroom for PC users?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/any-good-alternatives-to-lightroom-for-pc-users) for people who are truly looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Come to the light side. We may not [have cookies](https://www.starwars.com/shop/star-wars-housewares/come-to-the-dark-side-we-have-cookies), but we have *legitimate* free software. The creators of Photoshop, as is their right, decided to keep the internals of the program proprietary and to charge money for access and use.

But, other programmers have decided to take a different approach and created RAW-processing software like [Darktable](http://darktable.org/) and [Rawtherapee](https://rawtherapee.com/) which they share freely — the only cost being that if you make improvements to the software, you need to share them too.

You can download and use these programs with a free conscience — no "cracks" or other shenanigans, and if you have problems you can ask on their support forums without being chastised. You will be able to convert ARW images from your Sony 6300 without weird diagonal lines *or* guilt.

Comment: It's not even as extreme as "*if you make improvements to the software, you need to share them too*": if you *distribute* improvements to the software, you commit to distributing the source code for them.